# Solr AutoSuggest query response:: more than one field

Tags: solr, autocomplete, autosuggest

I have tried to use Facet based and Terms based approaches to implement AutoSuggest feature.

I am able to implement the feature with the query response containing a single field: The one on which the search is based.

Here, i want to return one additional field in the response as per the business requirements.

Scenario: The autosuggest query is currently returning a field which corresponds to the 'product name'. This is the field configured for autosuggest. Along with this I also want to return the 'product id' field. However, my autosuggest query should not be based on this 'product id' index.

Please suggest.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The "feature" you are looking for does not exist. Reason being, Solr suggests words that are repeated (based on `threshold`) in the index.

What you are looking for, I think, is a mixture of the `suggestor` and the `group by` query. Where the result is grouped on the basis of the word and the ids are sent along.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. How can we use the 'group by' logic in a SOLR query? Also, is it possible to use it with the Facet query?